# jquery ajax - setinterval to auto refresh only part of script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple chat system on my website. When I click on a user in the messages list, the data gets pulled from the database with AJAX. This script loads the PHP content of the chat:

```
function toggleMail(other) {

      jQuery.ajax({
        url: "fetch_message.php",
        data:'other='+other,
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
          $('#message').show();
          setInterval(function(){
            var scrollpos = $('#messages').scrollTop();
            $('#message').html(data);
            $('#messages').scrollTop(scrollpos);
          }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

My PHP script *fetch_message.php* contains something like this:

```
//--Some PHP code --
<div class="mail_header"><?php xxx ?></div> //with some information about the chat
<div class="mail_messages"><?php xxx ?></div> //with the conversation itself
<div class="mail_replybox"><?php xxx ?></div> //with the textarea to respond to the chat
```

I want to auto refresh the chat every 1 second. The problem is that it not only refreshes the conversation itself, but also the *mail_header* and *mail_replybox*, which should of course not happen. The *mail_header* and *mail_replybox* need data from the PHP code so they are all located in the same PHP script.

Does anyone know how I can get this to only refresh the middle part, i.e. the conversation and not the other *div*s? I have been working on this for days and can't get it to work...

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to refresh the chat when something happens, for instance when a user posts something, by using websockets etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `setInterval` at the wrong place: the server request is not repeated, and so the same data is put in the `message` element over and over again.

To only refresh the chat part, you could provide an argument in your server request (i.e. to PHP) so that it knows whether to produce the header, messages and replybox or just the messages.

Suggested PHP code changes:

```
<?php
   if (!isset($_POST['refresh'])) { // check absence of new argument
?>
<div class="mail_header"><?php xxx ?></div>
<div class="mail_messages"><?php xxx ?></div>
<div class="mail_replybox"><?php xxx ?></div>
<?php
   } else { // only refresh messages:
       echo xxx; // only chat content, without the <div class="mail_messages">
   }  
?>
```

Then in your JavaScript:

```
function toggleMail(other, refresh) { // second parameter added 
    // define arguments to pass in the request:
    var data = { other: other };
    if (refresh) data.refresh=1; // define new request parameter

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "fetch_message.php",
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
            var scrollpos = $('#messages').scrollTop();
            if (refresh) { // only populate chat
                $('#message .mail_messages').html(data);
            } else { // populate the whole lot
                $('#message').html(data).show();
            }
            $('#messages').scrollTop(scrollpos);
            // Send new refresh request in 1 sec:
            setTimeout(function(){
                toggleMail(other, 1)
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

The original call to *toggleMail* can stay like it is, with just the first argument.